# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/Registration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant, tomcat7

My eclipse environment has

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat Ec2 environment has

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Is this the root cause for the issue ?

I then tried to build the project on the EC2 server. I exported Ant build files and ran

> ant build

It ran successfully, but never created the class files or the war file. This ant exporting from eclipse has **NEVER** worked. Why does ant suck that much ? Is it a dead project ?

What am I missing on the **major.minor 51.0** issue ?

**EDIT**

```
Buildfile: /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/release/SwipeXBackEnd/build.xml
     [echo] Java Version via Ant: 1.7
     [echo] Java Version System Prop: 1.7.0_65

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:
     [echo] SwipeXBackEnd: /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/release/SwipeXBackEnd/build.xml

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

> Class files created in WEB-INF folder. But no **WAR** file

Comment: Which java-version `ant` is using?

Comment: there is no tag `java-version` in the build.xml.. what am I looking for here ?

Comment: Add `<echo>Java Version via Ant: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
    <echo>Java Version System Prop: ${java.version}</echo> `
to your ant script an you should see wich version ant is using.

Comment: [echo] Java Version via Ant: 1.7
     [echo] Java Version System Prop: 1.7.0_65

Comment: Same as java -version, mentioned in the question